# Running and debugging tests in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, phantomjs, karma-runner, protractor

I want to dockerize my entire node.js app and run everything inside a docker container, including tests.

It sounds easy if you're using PhantomJS and I actually tried that and it worked.

<strike>One thing I like though about running tests in Chrome - easy debugging. You could start Karma server, open devtools, set a breakpoint in a test file (using `debugger` statement) and run Karma - it will connect to the server run tests, and stop at the breakpoint, allowing you from there to do all sorts of things.</strike>

Now how do I do that in a docker container?

- Should I start Karma server (with Chrome) on a hosting machine and tell somehow Karma-runner inside the container to connect to it, to run the tests? (How do I do that anyway?)
- Is it possible to run Chrome in a docker container (it does sound like a silly question, but when I tried `docker search desktop` bunch of things come up, so I assume it is possible (?)
- Maybe it's possible to debug tests in PhantomJS (although I doubt it would be as convenient as with Chrome devtools)

Would you please share your experience of running and debugging Karma tests in a docker container?

**upd**: I just realized it's possible to run Karma server in the container and still debug tests just by navigating to Karma page (e.g. localhost:9876) from the host computer.

However, I still have a problem - I am planning to set and start using Protractor as well. Now those tests definitely need running in a real browser (PhantomJS has way too many quirks). Can anyone tell me how to run Protractor test from inside a docker container?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of `Protractor` and it's workflow, but if you need a browser inside a container, did you see [this](https://blog.jessfraz.com/posts/docker-containers-on-the-desktop.html) article? I'll take the liberty for quoting this:

```
$ docker run -it \
    --net host \ # may as well YOLO
    --cpuset 0 \ # control the cpu
    --memory 512mb \ # max memory it can use
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ # mount the X11 socket
    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \ # pass the display
    -v $HOME/Downloads:/root/Downloads \ # optional, but nice
    -v $HOME/.config/google-chrome/:/data \ # if you want to save state
    -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd --privileged \ # so we have sound
    --name chrome \
    jess/chrome
```

Comment: To run on mac this link is essential https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8710

Answer (score 1):

To dockerize your protractor test cases use either of this images from Dockerhub caltha/protractor (or) webnicer/protractor-headless.

Then run this command "docker run -it {imageid} protractor.conf.js". See the instructions in those repositories